# sort a mysql table column value by part of its value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `sample` with column-name `Id` which have values like

```
BA001
BA002
CAB003
BA004
BA005
```

Now when i apply `order by id` to my select query the output will look like

```
BA001
BA002
BA004
BA005
CAB003
```

But i need output in order

```
BA001
BA002
CAB003
BA004
BA005
```

Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: These we the employee ID's. for regular employees the id will look like `BA001`. but for contract employees the id will look like `CAB003`. So i need to order the table by employee Id with only numbers of the id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Assuming your Id column is a VARCHAR and you have a fixed number of characters as numbers in your Id and they appear on the right, you can use the RIGHT function in MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM sample ORDER BY RIGHT(Id, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT ID FROM Table1
Order By Right(ID,3),ID
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59895/5)

Comment: i think it works same even without the `ID(which is at the last)` in query

Comment: @user2979046 It is safe for your oder...because it will order by Numeric and ID too

Comment: If you have values CA004...then It will come under BA004

Comment: but the values will start only with `BA` or `CBA`

Comment: It's safty of odering...if you change the ID values otherwise you can use